# Replacing character in a text file with comma delimited

Tags: vb.net

I have a comma delimited file with sample values :
1,1076103,22-NOV-16,21051169,50,1083,AAA,TEXT

Question : how to replace the comma in the last column which is "AAA,TEXT"

The result should be this way:
1,1076103,22-NOV-16,21051169,50,1083,AAATEXT

Comment: If you want to take every time the last then split your string take the last 2 intem in the new array and merge. Finally take the others items in the array and put again a comma between them ;)

Comment: I got your point sir, but how if the last part has no comma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is simple, but learn a bit how to use string ;)

```
Public Function MDP(strWork As String)
    Dim splitted() As String = strWork.Split(","c)
    Dim firsts As New List(Of String)

    For i As Integer = 0 To splitted.Count - 3
        firsts.Add(splitted(i))
    Next

    Dim result As String = System.String.Join(",", firsts)

    Return result & "," & splitted(splitted.Count - 2) & splitted(splitted.Count - 1)
End Function
```

Then call with:

```
 Dim finished As String = MDP("1,1076103,22-NOV-16,21051169,50,1083,AAA,TEXT")
```

Comment: It works, the only problem is when the last set of values has no comma in the end.  sample values : (1,1076103,22-NOV-16,21051169,50,1083,AAA TEXT) the given result was this : (1,1076103,22-NOV-16,21051169,50,1083AAA TEXT)

Answer (score 2):

There is [an overload of String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda(v=vs.110).aspx) which takes an argument telling it the maximum number of parts to return. You could use it like this:

```
Option Infer On
Option Strict On

Module Module1

    'TODO: think up a good name for this function
    Function X(s As String) As String
        Dim nReturnParts = 7
        Dim parts = s.Split({","c}, nReturnParts)
        If parts.Count < nReturnParts Then
            Throw New ArgumentException($"Not enough parts - needs {nReturnParts}.")
        End If

        parts(nReturnParts - 1) = parts(nReturnParts - 1).Replace(",", "")
        Return String.Join(",", parts)

    End Function

    Sub Main()
        Dim s() = {"1,1076103,22-NOV-16,21051169,50,1083,AAA,TEXT",
            "1,1076103,22-NOV-16,21051169,50,1083,BBBTEXT",
            "1,1076103,22-NOV-16,21051169,50,1083,C,C,C,TEXT"}

        For Each a In s
            Console.WriteLine(X(a))
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Outputs:

> 1,1076103,22-NOV-16,21051169,50,1083,AAATEXT
>   1,1076103,22-NOV-16,21051169,50,1083,BBBTEXT
>   1,1076103,22-NOV-16,21051169,50,1083,CCCTEXT